# set rst (reStructuredText) filetype in vim

Tags: php, vim, syntax, restructuredtext

I am reading book/documentation in Vim written in **rst** (reStructuredText) format. Book is about PHP, so it is full of code. If I manually set filetype to PHP, code has syntax highlight.

```
set ft=php
```

But if place this line in my *.vimrc*, filetype is reckognized by vim, but there is no code syntax highlighting.

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile,FileType *.rst set ft=php
```

Anybody knows how to fix that ?

Thanks

Comment: The `'filetype'` option is unlikely to match '*.rst', so I would use just the usual `BufRead,BufNewFile`.  What does `:verbose set filetype? syntax?` tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirecting **all** reStructuredText files to show up as PHP looks wrong. Instead of messing with the filetype detection, I would rather explicitly specify the filetype:

```
:edit +setf\ php phpbook.rst
```

If there are several files, and this is permanent, I'd configure this path-based:

```
:autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile /path/to/dir/*.rst setf php
```

Alternatively, you can use one of the *local vimrc* plugins; there are several on vim.org; I can recommend the [localrc plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393), which even allows local filetype-specific configuration.

#### Alternative

With my [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168), you can keep the default reStructuredText syntax, and only mark the PHP snippet sections as PHP:

```
:12,42SyntaxInclude php
```

If the sections are delimited by certain patterns, this can even be automated.